# Accessibility of "Mayflower Steps" boat tours in Plymouth, England?

Tags: uk, accessibility

I am trying to help a blind woman arrange a trip with her daughter.  She's recently lost her sight, and has not yet acquired, much less learned to use, accessibility tools for phone and internet.

To further complicate things, she has to hang on to a walker all the time, and sometimes can't do steps (depends on how many and how big the rise of each).

The daughter wants to take a boat tour from the "Mayflower Steps" but the only time available to them is on a day that Plymouth already has over half its hotel rooms sold out.  (In other words, lots of people!)  So we need to decide quickly yes or no and if yes, get signed up before the boat sells out.  We don't really have time to hope that our web form query is answered by someone who actually knows something (or even answered at all).

Websites for Plymouth, for the Barbican, for the "steps", and for the boats did not help me determine whether there are actually any steps or anything else pertinent to this decision.  I don't have all the URIs handy, except one: 
http://www.visitplymouth.co.uk/things-to-do/the-mayflower-steps-p1398993

So, anyone able to provide specific details **on accessibility** there?  (or cite a useful URI that doesn't show up in web searches for "Plymouth, England" "Mayflower steps" or "boat tours" with either of the other two?)

Thanks

Comment: P.S. Are there tags for specific locations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [VisitPlymouth accessibility page](http://www.visitplymouth.co.uk/information/accessibility)  lists the accessible features and attractions.  They do include boat trips, which they cite as being accessible from the Barbican landing stage.

They also have a link to a Google Maps mashup, which allows zooming in on any of the landings, even to Google StreetView.

If that's not inspiring enough confidence, the best bet may be to contact the Visitor Information Center, on barbicantic@plymouth.gov.uk or by phone on 01752 306330.

Update: barbicantic eventually responded, and said that there is a ramp on the opposite side from the stairs. And that there would be people to make sure she steps from the dock to the boat safely.

Comment: Thanks, Mark (and @pnuts)!  I went to VisitPlymouth, but I didn't see that link till you posted it.  Aerial photos aren't very clear, and even StreetView is hard to be sure, but I think there are steps.  My friend however, decided to buy the ticket anyway, taking the chance that if she can't get to the boat, someone else will want her ticket.

Comment: @pnuts: I contacted the group sponsoring the conference she's going to and a response was that there should be people there to help her get on and off--but that refunding the ticket would be allowed if she feels intimidated.  They didn't really confirm or deny the layout though.  Barbicantic did not respond.